# Call method from subfolder

Tags: php, class, oop, methods

I run into problem, when i can't call methods.
structere is something like:

```
/www
  /classes
    /class.php
  /pages
    /page.php
  /index.php
```

so i want to call method from page.php file.
autoloader is configured in index.php file.
what is correct way to do so? i created object in index.php, and called method in page.php, but it throws `Fatal error: Call to a member function indexAboutMe() on a non-object in...`

i think, problem is index.php file don't pass object variable to page.php.

i use method from another class to include pages (works fine- html is included, but can't call method, because object variable is empty.), can this make this error?

code:

index.php

```
<?php


$page = $_GET['page'];
if (empty($page)){$page = 'sakums';}

function __autoload($class_name) {
    include './classes/' . $class_name . '.php';
}

$active = new activePage();
$db = new database();
?>

//then there is bunch of plain html code
 <?php
            $pageSwitcher = new pageSwitcher();
            $pageSwitcher->pageLoader($page);
        ?>  //this is page switching method, which includes file from pages folder
```

class for including pages:

```
<?php
/*
*class for page loading depending on active page.
*/

class pageSwitcher
{
    public function pageLoader($page)
    {
        switch ($page)
        {
            case 'sakums':
                include_once './pages/sakums.php';
                break;
}
}
}?>
```

and sakums.php which can't receive object variable:

```
//html here
<?php $db->indexAboutMe(); ?>
//html
```

Comment: Did you instantiate an object before trying to call the method?

Comment: yes, at very beggining of index.php-

Comment: Can you please show us your code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate the `$db` variable in the function including the pages or use `global $db;`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php for more info, just excited answering first question in stackOverflow

Comment: yes, i read about variable scope, that is why i got confused, $db is initiated in index.php, so it is global, but it didn't pass it to page.php.